# Random Modules and "randint()" function

Tags: python, function, random, import

I am a beginner Python user. I was wondering why I am unable to use two `randint()` functions. I've done a little research on the issue, and it seems as though "I can only have one random module active at any time". Is there any way to get around this so I can have two "random values"?

Also, this is my first question ever, so criticism towards the question, sample code and answer are all welcome.

```
import random

random = random.randint(1, 5)
random_2 = random.randint(7, 11)

print(random)
print(random_2)
```

Comment: You named your first value `random`, but that’s what the random module was named! Try `r` and `r_2` or something instead.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What's happening is that Python is confusing `random` (the number) with `random` (the module). Also, don't name the file `random.py` because it's going to search the module in the local directory, first.

And it's not a bug.

Comment: If module name was an issue, the first call of `random.randint` should fail with `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'randint'`. But OP had one random value, so this is not an cause of the problem.

Comment: I just said that because it is a "related" error that may have in the future.

Comment: The error is `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'randint'`. Both are AttributeError, but ....

Comment: That's one of the reasons that I put that, the other ones were that when I was learning the basics, I had that error, and that both talk about "confusion". Also, I did not express that it was an answer, because it was side note.

Comment: I misread your answer. my apologies.

Comment: Apology accepted :D